# How to check total cache size using a program

Tags: c, caching, size

so I'm having some trouble creating a program to measure cache size in C. I understand the basic concept of going about this but I'm still having trouble figuring out exactly what I am doing wrong.

Basically, I create an array of varying length (going by power of 2s) and access each element in the array and put it in a dummy variable. I go through the array and do this around 1000 times to negate the "noise" that would otherwise occur if I only did it once to get an accurate measurement for time. Then, I look for the size that causes a big jump in access time. Unfortunately, this is where I am having my problem, I don't see this jump using my code and clearly I am doing something wrong.

Another thing is that I used /proc/cpuinfo to check the cache and it said the size was 6114 but that was not a power of 2. I was told to go by powers of 2 to figure out the cache can anyone explain why this is?

Here is the just of my code...I will post the rest if need be

```
 {
    struct timeval start;
struct timeval end;
int n =1 ; // change this to test different sizes
int array_size = 1048576*n; // size of 1MB
int x = 0;
int i =0, j=0;
int *a;
int sum = 0;
a =malloc((array_size)*sizeof(int));



for(j=0; j < array_size; j ++)
    {

        a[j] = 1; // intialize all elements to 1


    }



gettimeofday(&start,NULL);

for(i=0; i<500; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j < array_size; j ++)
    {

        x += a[j];
    }
}



gettimeofday(&end,NULL);

      sum = x+8192;

int timeTaken = (end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec *1000000 + start.tv_usec);
printf("Time Taken: %d \n", timeTaken);
printf("Average: %f \n", (double)timeTaken/((double)array_size));
```

}

Comment: Please post your actual code (this can't be it, since there's an undeclared `x` variable used, as well as `start` and `end` which are not declared. This code also does nothing to try and calculate `cache size`; it simply iterates through each element of an array and throws away the value it reads (`x` is never used anywhere except when it's assigned `a[j]`, which means `a[j]` is just read for no reason). There's also nothing here related to "powers of 2", and your constant for the "size of 1MB" is wrong (should be `1048576`, which is a "power of 2").

Comment: even assuming the 'real' code is correct, you should check your memory read isn't being optimised out. You could try summing the memory content instead, and make sure you do something with the result.

Comment: Sorry,my fault I should have mentioned that the code I made is just trying to find the jump in execution time first. I apologize about that. I updated it so check whenever you can! Thanks! The issue is stemming from the fact that the time simply increases linearly and theres no jump

Comment: Your array size is a bit strange, as Ken pointed out. I'd start small - maybe 1k, rather than 1M. And as I said before, ensure the read is not being optimised out.

Comment: How would I go about making sure it does not optimize out? I tried summing it up but the average time taken per instruction doesn't change :S. I will try starting lower but I was told the cache size will be 1MB-16MB and I should malloc accordingly

Comment: If your compiler optimizes at all, it should discard the `x = a[j];` statement, since `x` is never used afterward. That leaves an empty loop (`for j =`), and that could be removed, leaving another empty loop (`for i`), which could be optimized away, which leaves pretty much `get start time; get end time;`, which should remain pretty constant. <g>

Comment: Hmm, okay so I changed it so that it adds up everything and does an arbitrary add near the end of 8192 (I edited it so that you can see it) would that be enough to cancel out any optimization going on? The thing is I still don't see a change in the average execution time

Comment: Try declaring a as volatile, e.g. `volatile int *a;` - this should prevent the read from being optimized out.

Comment: I tried this as well and no luck...I've even randomized the accesses and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could make sure that the array access it is not optimized, the `gettimeofday` doesn't have enough time resolution to measure a cache access, especially L1 (any recent commodity processors have 2 or 3 levels of cache).

You **may** get something with a nanosecond clock and **lots of statistics** to reduce the error of each measure.

On the other hand, you could use some third part library like PAPI (Performance API) that had [this kind of feature](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projects/papi/wiki/PAPIC%3apapi_mem_info.1) to get the information instead of measure.